# How can I get an IVsDropdownBar out of an EnvDTE.Window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I get notified whenever a new window is opened by this method:

```
private void OnWindowActivated(EnvDTE.Window GotFocus, EnvDTE.Window LostFocus)
```

What I want to do now is to get the selected method in the object `IVsDropdownBar`, whenever this is changed.

So how can I get a reference to this object?

Answer (score 3):

I haven´t tried that, so this answer is just an idea...

In accordance to MSDN you can obtain an `IVsDropdownBar` instance through the `IVsDropdownBarManager` service; the `GetDropdownBar` method returns the drop-down bar associated with the code window (might be the case that there isn´t a drop-down bar, since this addornment is language service specific and can be turned of via the options).

The documentation states that the `IVsDropdownBarManager` can be obtained from an `IVsCodeWindow`; I guess you can get such an instance from the active document window, somehow...

Once you have the `IVsDropdownBar` object, the `GetClient` and `GetCurrentSelection` methods might be of your interest; `GetCurrentSelection` allows you to query the selection for a certain drop-down; for instance...

```
IVsDropdownBar bar;
int hr = manager.GetDropdownBar(out bar);
if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK && bar != null)
{
    IVsDropdownBarClient barClient;
    hr = bar.GetClient(out barClient);
    if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK && barClient != null)
    {
        // const int TypesDropdown = 0;
        const int MembersDropdown = 1;

        int curSelection;
        hr = bar.GetCurrentSelection(MembersDropdown, out curSelection);
        if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK && curSelection >= 0)
        {
            hr = barClient.GetEntryText(MembersDropdown, curSelection, out text);
            if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure, if the obtained information is useful... 
The documentation states, it can be

> [...] plain or fancy text [...] and the drop-down code makes no assumption about their semantics.

Comment: Thanks! This works pretty well, except for the line where I try to get the entry text. There my extension crashes with an unhandled exception. I read the following on the MSDN documentation, but don't really understand it: "The text buffer returned in ppszText is typically created by the IVsDropdownBarClient object and the buffer must persist for the life of the IVsDropdownBarClient object.
If you are implementing this interface in managed code and you need to have the string disposed of by the caller, implement the IVsCoTaskMemFreeMyStrings interface on the IVsDropdownBarClient interface."

Comment: And btw, the flag for types dropdown is 1, members is 2 and project is 0.

Comment: I added a new question concerning this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28458715/ivsdropdownbarclient-and-text-buffers