# IVsDropdownBarClient and GetEntryText: Problems with text buffers

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

In my Visual Studio extension, I'm going to read the text that is in the navigation bar. Therefore I listen to window created events and from the IVsCodeWindow object I get the IVsDropdownBar to get the current selection in the dropdown bar. This works fine. Then I'm using the following code snippet to extract the text of the current selection:

```
 string text;
 barClient.GetEntryText(MembersDropdown, curSelection, out text);
 if (hr == VSConstants.S_OK)
 {
    Debug.WriteLine("Text: " + text);
 } else  {
    Debug.WriteLine("No text found!");
 }
```

However, this does not work. My extension crashes with an unhandled exception in the second line of the code snippet. I read the documentation and could find the following note:

> The text buffer returned in ppszText is typically created by the
>   IVsDropdownBarClient object and the buffer must persist for the life
>   of the IVsDropdownBarClient object. If you are implementing this
>   interface in managed code and you need to have the string disposed of
>   by the caller, implement the IVsCoTaskMemFreeMyStrings interface on
>   the IVsDropdownBarClient interface.

I assume that this is part of my problem, but I can't really understand what I have to change in my code to get it working. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure now that the Visual Studio SDK Interop DLLs have the wrong marshalling information for `IVsDropDownbarClient.GetEntryText` and that there's no way to call that method using that interface.

The best workaround I've found so far is:

1. Use the `tlbimp` tool to generate an alternate Interop DLL for textmgr. (You can safely ignore the dozens of warnings including the one about GetTextEntry.)

   tlbimp "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VSSDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Inc\textmgr.tlb"
2. (Optional) If you're using source control, you'll probably want to copy the resulting file (TextManagerInternal.dll) to a subdirectory of your extension project and check it in as an external dependency.
3. In your Visual Studio extension project, add a reference to the file (TextManagerInternal.dll).
4. Add the following method that should properly handle the string marshalling.

   ```
   static public string HackHackGetEntryText(IVsDropdownBarClient client, int iCombo, int iIndex)
   {
       TextManagerInternal.IVsDropdownBarClient hackHackClient = (TextManagerInternal.IVsDropdownBarClient) client;

       string szText = null;
       IntPtr ppszText = IntPtr.Zero;

       try
       {
           ppszText = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr)));
           if(ppszText == IntPtr.Zero)
               throw new Exception("Unable to allocate memory for IVsDropDownBarClient.GetTextEntry string marshalling.");

           hackHackClient.GetEntryText(iCombo, iIndex, ppszText);

           IntPtr pszText = Marshal.ReadIntPtr(ppszText);

           szText = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(pszText);
       }
       finally
       {
           if(ppszText != IntPtr.Zero)
               Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ppszText);
       }

       return szText;
   }
   ```

   }